Getting Last enabled date of JBOSS server using backend code with java
I am thinking to get a last enabled date of the JBOSS server by passing CLI command through JAVA code.
But I am not getting CLI command to get last enabled date from the JBOSS server. please let me know if there is a CLI command to get last enabled date from JBOSS server.

What do you mean by the "last enabled date"? Do you mean when the server was started?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
